# Similarity between an item and a set

Tags: similarities, recommender-system

I have two items $I_0$ and $I_1$ and a set $S$. What I want to achieve is to compare which item (either $I_0$ or $I_1$) is more similar to the set.

I can compare both $I_0$ and $I_1$ to every element in the set and compute 2 vectors where each element is the similarity between the given item and each member of the set. However, I am not sure what to do with the resulting vectors in order to compare the similarities.

Calculating the sum of all members in the vector and then comparing the sums seems to make sense since both vectors would have equal length.

I was thinking, are there any standard methods to do this (i.e. deciding what to do with the similarities vectors)?

Comment: I don't think there can be any one "standard" way. A similarity between an item and a set is a similarity between the item and some characteristic of a set which "makes" the set. The characteristic could be [extensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_(semantics)) (i.e. the list of members)  or [intensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intension)(such as mean or median or other _emergent_ things). And there can be infinite ways (a specific formula) to measure the similarity.